# overload on-click event in kibana dashboards embedded in iframes

Tags: javascript, iframe, kibana-4

I am new to Kibana and just discovered that I can easily embed Kibana dashboards into iframes to include in separate webpages.

I would like to be able to click on specific panels inside the dashboard and bring up separate windows where I would display analogous splunk querys.

Is it possible to override the on-click event in the kibana dashboard to add this behavior.

The documentation I have found for kibana is a bit cursory so I would also appreciate any resources you can send my way.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to override the on-click event in the kibana dashboard, but the project is open-source so you could definitely create a version that behaves this way.

Kibana 4 development is explained in the [CONTRIBUTING.md](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md) at the root of the github repository. I recommend you start there.

Those directions explain the following in more detail:

1. setting up your development environment

   - install `node.js` and `git`
   - check out the kibana repo
   - run `npm install` to install dependencies
2. running Kibana in "dev" mode with `./node_modules/.bin/grunt dev`

   - in dev mode your updates are immediately available in the browser
3. building distributable packages with `./node_modules/.bin/grunt build`

The part of Kibana that you will likely want to modify or extend is the [dashboard app's panel directive](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/blob/master/src/kibana/plugins/dashboard/components/panel/panel.js).

Hope that helps!